# How to calculate max temperature craft needs to withstand near the Sun

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, sun, space-mission, solar-wind

The Solar Probe Plus [fact-sheet](http://solarprobe.jhuapl.edu/common/content/SolarProbePlusFactSheet.pdf) states that the craft will approach to the distance of 9 solar radii to the surface of the Sun (Approx 6.26e6 km) and its heat shields must withstand 1644K of heat.

I wonder how did they arrive at this number? Based on that, how can I calculate the max temperature an object has to withstand at 3.68e6 km (about 5 solar radii)?

Of course I know that at some point simple formula wouldn't work as we'll enter corona.

Comment: It's written 1664 K. The degree symbol isn't supposed to be used with kelvin.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_equilibrium_temperature

Comment: They probably used that model, with some assumed albedo $a$.

Comment: Just to clarify, Solar Probe Plus will go to within ~8.5 solar radii from the surface (~9.5 from the center) at its closest approach.  But you should note that it's not just high temperatures that need to be dealt with but also ionization of the spacecraft and radiation damage...

Comment: @Spirko the number 1664 is the Kronenbourg Constant

Comment: @Dirk, must have been a Freudian slip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The energy per unit area radiated by an object at a temperature $T$ is given by the [Stefan-Boltzmann law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law):

$$ J = \varepsilon\sigma T^4 \tag{1} $$

where $\sigma$ is the [Stefan-Boltzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_constant) and $\varepsilon$ is the [emissivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emissivity). A spaceship in a vacuum can only lose heat by radiation, so it will heat up until the energy loss given by equation (1) is equal to the rate of energy absorption from the Sun. So if we calculate the energy flux from the Sun and plug it into equation (1) we can solve for the temperature.

However there's an easier way to do the calculation. Suppose the temperature of the Sun's surface is $T_s$ and it radiates some energy flux $J_s$ given by (the emissivity of the Sun is close to one):

$$ J_s = \sigma T_s^4 $$

If we go out to a distance of $n$ solar radii then the area goes up as $r^2$ so the energy flux per unit area is $J_n = J_s/n^2$ so:

$$ \frac{J_s}{n^2} = \sigma T_n^4 $$

where $T_n$ is the temperature at our distance of $n$ solar radii. Substituting for $J_s$ gives:

$$ \frac{\sigma T_s^4}{n^2} = \sigma T_n^4 $$

which rearranges to:

$$ T_n = \frac{T_s}{\sqrt{n}} $$

So at 9 solar radii we get:

$$ T = \frac{T_s}{3} $$

and since the temperature of the surface of the Sun is 5778K we get:

$$ T = 1926\,\text{K} $$

This is higher than the figure your article mentions, though only by 17%. Presumably the difference is down to the emissivity of the Solar probe.

Comment: Why only the temperature of the surface of the Sun is factored in when temperature of its corona is thousands of times higher?

Comment: @Czar: the energy flux from the corona is insignificant compared to the flux from the surface. The corona is too dilute to make a significant contribution to the total energy flux.

Comment: So mirrored on the sun side and black on the other will make no difference?

Comment: @DirkBruere: good point, the object is only being irradiated from one side but it's radiating over its entire surface. However IIRC satellites include a cooling system with a radiator that runs at well above the equilibrium temperature. So the simple model I describe above would at best be a rough guide for a real satellite.

Comment: @DirkBruere - There will be a rather large carbon-carbon heat shield on the sun-facing side while the rest of the craft is meant to stay in shadow.  The solar panels are attached to movable arms allowing them to cant in/out depending on distance from the sun.  The cool part is that some of the instruments will actually need to be heated even when at ~$8.5 \ R_{s}$ because in shadow it is still really cold (thermal conduction of heat to a spacecraft from the plasma is negligible).